# Get Instagram Stories Json

Tags: android, json, api, instagram

How can I get Instagram Stories in JSON Object by using Instagram API? I have tried using the following URL, but I am getting this error.

```
// https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/MY_USER_ID/reel_media/

{
  "message": "login_required",
  "logout_reason": 2,
  "status": "fail"
}
```

Code :

```
String id = userInfoHashmap.get(InstagramApp.TAG_ID);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/"+id +"/reel_media/?access_token="+mApp.getTOken(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("ID: ", String.valueOf(response));
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: bro, you have to login.

Comment: where to add the authorization code in the Api Url. I got the authorization token.

Comment: show some code.

Comment: @Orvenito see my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no official API for Instagram Stories.

In order to authenticate the request to that unofficial API endpoint, you must send a device 'sessionid', not your Instagram app's access token.

You can read my Medium article describing what you need to make a successful request to retrieve Instagram Stories: https://medium.com/@calialec/chrome-ig-story-bribing-the-instagram-story-api-with-cookies-c813e6dff911

Also, check out my GitHub repo to see where I'm injecting the cookies into the request: https://github.com/CaliAlec/ChromeIGStory/blob/master/event/src/index.js#L167

Comment: Hi. I have the same issue now. It appeared just a day ago for me :( I use all 3 cookies: `sessionid` (I regenerate it for each session), `csrftoken` and `ds_user_id`

Comment: @Alec I have not found github project, can you help me please.

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Due to a Cease & Desist letter from Facebook, I have been forced to take down the GitHub repo.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the Instagram API Documentation? It [states](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) that you need an access token to make any call to the API. Add your access token as query parameter to your endpoint.

Comment: Here is my api that i am using https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/MY_USER_ID/reel_media/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN but same error

Comment: You should change the URL to the documented form: https://api.instagram.com/v1/feed/user/MY_USER_ID/reel_media/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Try to paste the URL to a browser. You should get your desired result there. Otherwise your access token may have expired

Comment: Same error. Can you make sure, it is the same URL required to fetch Instagram stories?

Comment: Have a look at sandbox mode.
https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: @redead this url is not working can you please help me for that